# Disable Specific days, Specific Dates, and Specific Months, datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to disable some days from the date picker. So far i was able to disable Sundays and Mondays, and the months of Jan and Feb. Now I'm stuck on trying to disable specific dates

2014/11/27, 2014/12/24, 2014/12/24

Everything i have tried has not worked. I am very new to all this and dont really know what im doing wrong.

here is my code so far

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
   dateFormat : 'yy/mm/dd',
   beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays, 
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   firstDay: 0  
    });

var daysToDisable = [0, 1];
var monthsToDisable = [0, 1];

function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];

    }

    return [true];
}       


});
```

and i would like to know if you can disable mondays and sundays for a certain date range, say from 9/1/2014 to 5/31/14.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE 9/26/14**

Thanks to TimSPQR if have figured this out. here is my code for anyone interested in this

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
   dateFormat : 'yy/mm/dd',
   beforeShowDay: unavailable, 
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   firstDay: 0  
    });

var months = ["January",    "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]  
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var unavailableDates = ["2014/11/27","2014/12/25","2014/12/24"]; // yyyy/MM/dd
var unavailableDays = ["Monday","Sunday"];
var unavailableMonths = ["January", "February"]
var lowrange = new Date('5/25/2015');
var highrange = new Date('9/7/2015');
var lowrange2 = new Date('5/25/2016');
var highrange2 = new Date('9/7/2016');



    function unavailable(date) {
        ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
        month = new Date(ymd).getMonth();
        if (
        ((lowrange < date && date < highrange) && date.getDay() === 0) ||
        ((lowrange < date && date < highrange) && date.getDay() == 1) ||
        ((lowrange2 < date && date < highrange2) && date.getDay() === 0) ||
        ((lowrange2 < date && date < highrange2) && date.getDay() == 1) ||
        ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0 && $.inArray(months[month], unavailableMonths) < 0) 
        )
        {
            return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
        } else {
            return [false,"disabled","Closed"];
        }
    }



    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for your specific dates and Sunday Monday [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vrMq/3/).

Just put your exclusion dates in the array.

JS

```
var enabledDays = ['9/24/2014','9/26/2014','9/29/2014','10/25/2014'];

$(".mydate").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disabledAll,
    beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
                                              instance.dpDiv.css({
                                                          marginTop: 2,
                                                          marginLeft: 1
                                                                  });
                                              }
                         });

function disabledAll(date)
{
 var m = date.getMonth() + 1, d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
 for ( var i=0; i < enabledDays.length; i++ )
     {
      if( $.inArray( m + '/' + d + '/' + y, enabledDays) != -1 )
        {
         return [0];
         }
      }
 return [1];
}
```

---

### I'll play around a little to see if it's possible to do multiple exclusions as you are requesting.

Edit: Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vrMq/4/) that does what you want without the for loop.

Edit: derived from [HERE](http://www.sourcecodemart.com/10-different-example-of-jquery-datepicker/).

Comment: Thank so much! this should work for me. i think i should be able to add to this to disable jan. and feb.

Comment: No problem. I've played around with it a bit since I posted, and it seems fairly flexible. If I come up with something more elegant, I'll post it.